# Is there any catchall in swift?

Tags: swift

I have varying input that will be a String like:

```
"James"
"James(1)"
"James(2)"
```

I'm looking to insert the values for these keys into a dictionary only after I remove the `(x)`

What can I use to represent `x` to then remove the entire parenthesis?

My current attempt looks like this:

`replacingOccurrences(of: "(\((Any).self)", with: "")`

But that's not working..

Desired output would be a dictionary only containing the one unique value as the key.

So with the input of

```
["James" : 3, "James(1)" : 3, "James(2)" : 4, "Sarah" : 10, "Sarah(1)" : 10, "Sarah(2)" : 10 ]
```

I would get this output

```
["James" : 10, "Sarah" : 30]
```

Comment: Do you need the values in brackets/parenthesis `()`? I'm not quite sure I fully understand what you are looking for, maybe showing an example input and the result would help.

Comment: @George I don't need the values in `()` , sorry for the ambiguity, I just added more context to my original question

Comment: Thanks for adding more detail. Should the value be the sum of all the original values? (if so, doesn't work for Sarah). Or is it just any random number?

Comment: @George sorry! miscalculation, fixing now

Comment: Yes, the value should be sum of all original values

Comment: Interesting, where is this data set coming from? Is there a more convenient form you could process, instead? As-is, your best bet is probably a regex like `#"\(\d+)?$"#` off the end

Comment: @Alexander Well.. myself.. I had a mock coding interview where I had to add duplicate keys with unique values into a dictionary.. next time I'll choose an easier separator..

Comment: @SergioBost You've programmed yourself into a corner. You made an inappropriate choice of dictionary key, and now you're wondering how to split it back apart. You should instead make a struct that conforms to Hashable, and use that to store your name and "sequence number" (or whatever it is)

Comment: @Alexander Agreed, lesson learned

Comment: @SergioBost Do you need help/guidance on replacing the strings with structs?

Comment: @Alexander If its trivial then yes please, I've been thinking about how to implement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235809/discussion-between-alexander-and-sergio-bost).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way would be to use [`reduce(into:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126956-reduce).

It works by:

1. Starting with an empty dictionary to create in the `reduce`.
2. Get index of first bracket/parenthesis (`nil` if none)
3. Get the name excluding anything after the `(`. Otherwise take whole name.
4. Append the value from the input for the current key as the name. If the name doesn't exist yet, default value of `0` is given.

Code:

```
let input = ["James": 3, "James(1)": 3, "James(2)": 4, "Sarah": 10, "Sarah(1)": 10, "Sarah(2)": 10]

let output: [String: Int] = input.reduce(into: [:]) { partialResult, pair in
    let firstBracket = pair.key.firstIndex(of: "(")
    let basicName = String(pair.key.prefix(upTo: firstBracket ?? pair.key.endIndex))
    partialResult[basicName, default: 0] += pair.value
}

print(output)
// Prints: ["James": 10, "Sarah": 30]
```

Answer (score 4):

I like George's solution, but I think this is a nice use case for `uniquingKeysWith:`.

```
// Convert to [(name, value)], removing everything after "("
let keyValues = data.map { k, v in (String(k.prefix(while: { $0 != "(" })), v) }


// Sum matching values
let result = Dictionary(keyValues, uniquingKeysWith: +)
```

Comment: Nice, can you explain what's going on there with the `+`

Comment: When two keys match, combine the existing value with the new value using `+`. `+` is just a function that takes two values and returns a value. Writing `+` here is identical to `{ (previous, new) in previous + new }`

Comment: Very nice! And only two lines of code at that.